# Presto on EMR: external access

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, presto

I have setup an EMR cluster with Presto installed and running. I can query my data on the server using `presto-cli`, but I am not entirely sure how to configure Presto to be accessible externally (e.g. from Tableau on my laptop).

I have looked at all the configuration/properties files in `/usr/lib/presto/`, but none of them seem to have anything to do with remote access setup (i.e. setting up user credentials and port).

My question is, how does one go about setting up remote access? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I was able to connect to Presto (thanks to @franklinsijo); here are the nitpicks:

- change the discovery URI in `config.properties` to the EMR server's public DNS
- ensure that your local IP address is whitelisted to access the port specified in `config.properties`

Comment: are you setup Kerberos authentication for presto external access?

Comment: huh, don't need password for presto external access.
i try exeternal access to presto from dbeaver. i only input private dns, user (ec2-user) for prest connect using ssh tunnel.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Presto Web connector for Tableau can be configured to run queries from Tableau. Unlike other tableau connectors, you cannot run live queries on Presto but can create tableau extracts. Refer [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/tableau.html) for configuration procedure.

As with configurations from Presto end, edit the configurations of Presto coordinator in `config.properties` file. The value of `discovery.uri` is required to setup the Tableau connector.

Comment: @Radix username would be the user running the presto process.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of setting up a password? Or anyone with the URI and the username can access Presto? (assuming their IP address is whitelisted)

Comment: No, None I am aware of. You might have to setup Kerberos authentication for this.

Comment: So I tried replacing the URI in config.properties with the server's public DNS, but was still unable to connect to it through Tableau. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a trailing `/` in the end of discovery.uri?

Comment: No; it's like this: `http://ec2-****.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8889`.